# How to deal with multi-level menus on touch screen devices which are using :hover and :focus for clickable top-level links?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, touch

Have a look at the following menu:

```css
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul {
  margin:10px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:yellow;
  list-style-type:none;
  position:relative;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul > li {
  float:left;
  margin:20px;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul > li > a {
  padding:20px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:block;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul > li > div.sub {
   position:absolute;
   top:calc(100%  - 20px);
   background-color:red;
   padding:40px;
   display:none;
   left:0;
   width:100vw;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul > li a:hover + div.sub, #my-menu-inner > ul > li a:focus + div.sub,
#my-menu-inner > ul > li > div.sub:hover, #my-menu-inner > ul > li > div.sub:focus {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="whatever">Just something before ...</div>
<div id="my-menu">
  <div id="my-menu-inner">
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/foo/">foo</a>
        <div class="sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/mobile/">mobile</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/users/">users</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/bar/">bar</a>
        <div class="sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/never/">never</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/see-me/">see me</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a nicely working menu for everybody who is having a mouse or a touchpad. However: Users of mobile devices will never ever see the submenu as they instantly go to the `href` location as soon as they click one of the links. And they do not have hover states, ofc.

What I thought about:

**Idea 1**: Have a seperate mobile menu for touch devices. This is great because most designs have seperate mobile menus anyway.

Problem: `@media screen (max-width: 1000px)` will not be a sufficient method to detect if a user is able to hover/focus as everyone with a large touchscreen for instance would be excluded.

**Idea 2:** `preventDefault()` on clicking the links. Check if mouse movement was detected before and if so, follow the link. If not require a second click.

Problem: Requiring two clicks is probably not user friendly (many will not recognize the link is clickable).

***What is a good and recommended way to deal with this situation?***

Answer (score 1):

I think a good practise is to make a visible clickable element. You should not only think about the implementation but about how the user will interact. The user need to know there is a sub menu and to do this you can add a small icon that may appear everywhere even if we can `:hover`.

Here is a simplified example where hover work by default. In case we cannot hover, we can click the icon to show the menu. Simply use an icon that make the click intuitive for users.

```js
$('li span').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.sub').toggleClass('show');
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul {
  margin:10px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:yellow;
  list-style-type:none;
  position:relative;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul > li {
  float:left;
  margin:20px;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul > li > a {
  padding:20px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
}
#my-menu-inner > ul > li > span {
  text-decoration:none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px 5px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-right:-10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#my-menu-inner > ul > li > span:before {
  content:"▼"
}
#my-menu-inner > ul > li > span.open:before {
  content:"▲"
}

#my-menu-inner > ul > li > div.sub {
   position:absolute;
   top:calc(100%  - 20px);
   background-color:red;
   padding:40px;
   display:none;
   left:0;
   width:100vw;
}

#my-menu-inner > ul > li a:hover ~ div.sub,
#my-menu-inner > ul > li span:hover ~ div.sub,
#my-menu-inner > ul > li a:focus ~ div.sub,
#my-menu-inner > ul > li span:focus ~ div.sub,
#my-menu-inner > ul > li > div.sub:hover, 
#my-menu-inner > ul > li > div.sub:focus,
#my-menu-inner > ul > li > div.sub:hover, 
#my-menu-inner > ul > li > div.sub.show{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="whatever">Just something before ...</div>
<div id="my-menu">
  <div id="my-menu-inner">
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/foo/">foo</a><span></span>
        <div class="sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/mobile/">mobile</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/users/">users</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/bar/">bar</a><span></span>
        <div class="sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/never/">never</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/see-me/">see me</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
       <li>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/bar/">I don't have submenu</a>
        
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 as this is useful input and solves part of the problem, but it does still not yet solve the problem with touch and double click

Comment: @Blackbam why it doesn't solve the touch issue? now you are able to click the icon t show the menu, no?

Comment: It is a good solution if the designers and UX testers accept it ;-)